# Remove border from a PowerPoint chart

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

I am creating charts in PowerPoint by making an Add-in. I am encountering a quite frustrating problem. Whenever you select a chart in PowerPoint a rectangular box appears around the chart and I want to remove this box. But I don't know what API to call or object to use to remove or hide that box

[image: The rectangular box around the chart]

I have tried using the `Chart.ChartArea` property but it doesn't help. Need help with this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can remove this box. It is a part of the Office UI, telling you that the chart is currently selected. As such it is a part of the core Office functionality which you cannot change.

I can't imagine how you could position or resize the chart without knowing where it's borders are.

Comment: I have seen this box removed by some PowerPoint Add-ins, think-cell <www.think-cell.com> is one example. When you select a think-cell chart it shows the box for half a second but then removes/hides it.

Comment: But is the chart still selected then? If not you could do this: in chart activate make a delay of 0.5s and then deactivate the chart.

Comment: The chart is still selected. And you can still resize and move the chart using the chart's plotarea.

Comment: FWIW: The name of the thing you want to hide is "sizing handles".

Comment: Think-Cell (the plugin you are referring to) are not using PowerPoint charts, but have rather created their own proprietary chart engine, thus they don't "remove" this border, it is just never there in their engine.